# How to download files properly using FileSystemResource in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, download, spring-boot

I have this following code for downloading files :-

```
@Controller
public class FileController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/files/{file_name:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public FileSystemResource getFile(@PathVariable("file_name") String fileName) {

        return new FileSystemResource("C:/Users/sourav/fileServer/"+fileName);

    }

}
```

When I go to the link for the first time nothing is displayed .When I reload only a text file with name f.txt is downloaded instead of the pdf file. I want the pdf file to be displayed in the browser. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: I have the same problem, using Spring 4.3.4

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the response headers. Otherwise there is no way for the browser to intuit the file format. Something like `response.setContentType("application/pdf");`.

Comment: You're right have to add media type to the header. This is another example of how to do:`@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{file_name:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE )` or `@GetMapping(value = "/files/{file_name:.+}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)`

Answer (score 0):

your code is ok. I think if you try with pdf file it will work as you expected, it will be displayed in browser. I tested it and worked fine in Chrome and Firefox. May be your testing file is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot, you can add the  MIME types of the files you want to download into `spring.mvc.mediaTypes` properties in the configuration file. For example:

```
spring.mvc.mediaTypes.yml=text/yaml
```

Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4220